# Flutter Singleton Usage without late

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization, singleton

I have learned the how can I use singleton class. After that, I wanted to use for my baseUrl class.

```
class BaseUrls {
  BaseUrls._();
  static BaseUrls get instance => BaseUrls._();
  final String baseUrl="https://pub.dev/packages/";
  late final String bloc="${baseUrl}bloc";
}
```

when I wants to use any variable for instance bloc, I can use it like

```
BaseUrls.instance.bloc
```

but when
I wants to use baseUrl inside of the bloc variable, I'm encountering the init error. I have solved that problem thanks to late usage. But in this time, there is a performance problem of late. when I use the late, it is harmful for ram usage.

So, my question is How can I use that usage without late? I mean, I wanna use the base url and bloc variable with together.

I'm open the new usage or best practices.
Many thanks.

Comment: You can declare `baseUrl` as `static` to be able to remove `late` on `bloc`

Answer (score 0):

finally,I have found 2 ways. First one is use static for baseUrl. Second way is use get function instead of bloc variable.

Summary:

```
//FIRST ONE
class BaseUrls {
  BaseUrls._();
  static BaseUrls get instance => BaseUrls._();
  final String baseUrl="https://pub.dev/packages/";
  final String get bloc="${baseUrl}bloc";
}

//SECOND WAY
    class BaseUrls {
        BaseUrls._();
        static BaseUrls get instance => BaseUrls._();
        static const String baseUrl="https://pub.dev/packages/";
        final String bloc="${baseUrl}bloc";
        }
```

so, which one if I use ,app will be more performance?
Should I use getter function or only use static to baseUrl?
Thanks....